# NullReferenceException while adding item to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7.1, observablecollection

I am trying to add an object to an ObservableCollection. As mentioned in a few question on this very site, I even tried to instantiate the collection before adding item. However, I am still getting the error. Here is my observation collection:

```
//Datacontext for local database
private WordDataContext wordsDB;

//Observable collection for binding
private ObservableCollection<WordItem> _wordItems = new ObservableCollection<WordItem>();
public ObservableCollection<WordItem> WordItems
{
    get
    {
        return _wordItems;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_wordItems != value)
        {
            _wordItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("WordItems");
        }
    }
}
```

I have overridden onNavigatedTo

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Define the query to gather all of the idea items.
        var wordItemsInDB = from WordItem word in wordsDB.WordItems
                            select word;

        // Execute the query and place the results into a collection.
        WordItems = new ObservableCollection<WordItem>(wordItemsInDB);

        // Call the base method.
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

And here is the button to add new item

```
    private void newIdeaAddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //// Create a new idea item based on the text box.
        //WordItem newIdea = new WordItem { WordName = "TestTest" };
        //Debug.WriteLine("I'm here!");
        //// Add a idea item to the observable collection.
        //WordItems.Add(newIdea);

        //// Add a idea item to the local database.
        //wordsDB.WordItems.InsertOnSubmit(newIdea);
        WordItem newword = new WordItem { WordName = "Bingo" };
        if (WordItems == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("I'm null!");
            WordItems = new ObservableCollection<WordItem>();
        }

        WordItems.Add(newword);
        wordsDB.WordItems.InsertOnSubmit(newword);
        Debug.WriteLine("Did something!");
    }
```

And here's the XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <!--<ListBox Margin="14,0,-12,0" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}">
            <ListBoxItem Content="About" Tap="GoToAbout"/>
        </ListBox>-->
        <telerikData:RadJumpList x:Name="TestList" IsStickyHeaderEnabled="True" Margin="14,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding WordItems}">
            <telerikData:RadJumpList.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                                                    
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="74">                                    
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Bully" Width="20" Fill="Gray" Height="62" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Text="{Binding WordItem}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </StackPanel>                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikData:RadJumpList.ItemTemplate>

            <telerikData:RadJumpList.StickyHeaderTemplate>                    
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" Height="74">
                        <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="62" Height="62">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Padding="7,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="White" />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikData:RadJumpList.StickyHeaderTemplate>

            <telerikData:RadJumpList.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" Height="74">
                        <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="62" Height="62">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Padding="7,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="White" />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikData:RadJumpList.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <telerikData:RadJumpList.GroupPickerItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemHeight="111" ItemWidth="111"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </telerikData:RadJumpList.GroupPickerItemsPanel>

            <telerikData:RadJumpList.GroupPickerItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="99" Height="99" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="White" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikData:RadJumpList.GroupPickerItemTemplate>
        </telerikData:RadJumpList>
        <Button x:Name="newIdeaAddButton" Click="newIdeaAddButton_Click" Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: In which line exactly are you getting the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the ObservableCollection. Most likely wordsDB is null

Comment: I agree - wordsDB could be null.

Comment: Are you raising an event without first checking if it is null? For example if you have an event Event which people can subscribe to, then when firing it you need to do if (Event != null) { Event(this, eventArgs); }. The reason I think this might be the case is that it looks like you're calling NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Spontifixus I'm getting the error in line `WordItems.Add(newword)` in the button's click event.
@Chasemedallion I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Sorry, I'm just a beginner. Can you suggest something in context of code, please? It might feel like spoonfeeding!

Comment: @akshay2000 could you post the exception details (by copying them or posting a screenshot where all relevant details are fully visibly: Message, InnerException and StackTrace)

Comment: @Spontifixus Here is full Stacktrace: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6169075/Stacktrace.txt

Shall I get full .cs too?

Comment: @akshay2000, thanks for posting - I'm on my way home, so I will look at that later this evening or tomorrow.

Comment: @akshay2000 could you please debug that issue, and tell us the values of `WordItems`, `wordsDB` and `wordsDB.WordItems` at the time of the exception?

Comment: @Spontifixus Thanks a lot for help! Here it goes: WordItems: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[LLS.WordItem]
wordsDB: LLS.WordDataContext (Yes, the namespace)
wordsDB.WordItems: Table(WordItem)
Then there is line of exception: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Telerik.Windows.Core.dll
Does this help? I am okay with uploading the whole solution in case needed.

Comment: There seems to be no reason for a `NullReferenceException` there. When you press F5 after that exception had occurred does your program continue?

Comment: @Spontifixus I finally found the error! I had groupdescriptor `            GenericGroupDescriptor<string, string> testgroup = new GenericGroupDescriptor<string, string>(listitem => listitem.Substring(0, 1).ToLower());
            this.TestList.GroupDescriptors.Add(testgroup);` which was raising the exception. I made some changes to it and everything seems fine now! So, do I answer my own question or something?

Comment: @akshay2000 Great! That's it, post your solution and mark it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally got the solution! The problem in itself is a bit obscure. The thing is that, earlier, I had RadJumplist bound to a `List<strings>` and it had GroupDescriptor defined accordingly

```
GenericGroupDescriptor<string, string> testgroup = new GenericGroupDescriptor<string, string>(listitem => listitem.Substring(0, 1).ToLower());
```

However, the scenario in question is about `ObservableCollection<WordItem>`. As soon as an item is added to the collection, the RadJumpList is notified about those changes and the GroupDescriptor proves to be invalid in that context. That somehow raises the `NullReferenceException`. It's a bit unintuitive to relate the error with the cause.

So, the simple solution was to change the descriptor as follows

```
GenericGroupDescriptor<WordItem, string> gengd = new GenericGroupDescriptor<WordItem, string>();
        gengd.KeySelector = (WordItem item) =>
            {
                char keyhead = item.WordName[0];
                return keyhead.ToString().ToLower();
            };
```

This thing is not really well documented!